# Is there a correct way to list the subdirectories of the current directory?

Tags: bash, command-line, directory, ls

I can find the subdirectories of a directory by

```
ls -d -- */
```

or

```
ls -l | grep "^d"
```

but both of these seem indirect, and I would imagine that there would be a standard way to find just the directories. Is there a right way to do this? And if not, will either of these lead to undesirable behavior on edge cases? (Symbolic links, hidden directories, etc.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer will depend more on what you intend to **do with** the output than on what you are looking for. If you just want to see a list for visual reference at the terminal, your first solution is actually pretty nice. If you want to process the output you should consider using another method.

One of the most robust ways to get a list to feed into another program is to use `find`.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

The reason this is good for feeds is that `find` can output the data separated by nulls using `-print0` or properly escape strings as arguments to another programs using `-exec`. For reference on why this is better than parsing the output of ls, see [ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) on Greg's Wiki.

Comment: I had to type `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d` to get this to work on OS X Yosemite.

Comment: to list the sub-directories, one has to also specify -mindepth as in  `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`. Otherwise, the current directory `.` will be included.

Answer (score 5):

FYI - In ZSH (but not BASH), you can also do this: `ls -d -- *(/)`; [the `(/)` modifier](http://www.phwinfo.com/forum/comp-unix-shell/397194-zsh-ksh-glob-directories-symlinks-directories.html)  tells ZSH only to glob directories.

That said, it isn't very different from your own proposed solution (`ls -d -- */`), and it's far from standard.

As far as the output of `ls` (which probably differs based on other flags):

```
% ls
dir0 dir1 dir2 file0 file1 file2
% ls -d -- */
dir0/ dir1/ dir2/
% ls -d -- *(/)
dir0 dir1 dir2
```

Comment: zsh expands the asterisk to all files and directories, the (/) flag selects parts of that expansion so **ls *(/)** would also work, as well as **echo *(/)**, or a more zshly way **print -l *(/)**. The two first versions also work in bash.

Comment: Note that `*(/)` expands to the non-hidden directories while `*/` expands to non-hidden directories or symlinks to directories (or at least symlinks to paths for which we can tell that they are directories).